# Django forms: Get foreign key values in template

Tags: django

In the template, while displaying a form, I want to display foreign key values as label and not as a select field, so that I can put input field for each of them.

Models:

```
class Attribute(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.key
```

The Attribute model is loaded with initial data of "size", "color", "gender" for example.

```
class Variation(models.Model):
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(Attribute, blank=False, null=False)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
```

Forms:

```
class VariationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Variation
        fields = "__all__"
```

template:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in variation_form %}
        {% for attribute in field.attribute %}
           {{ attribute }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

{{ attribute }} gives all the attributes in a select widget. How do I just get their names/key/value in the template, iterate over them and put input field in each of them ?

Answer (score 0):

Take look at [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets). Using them you can make separate inputs for each foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Or just change:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in variation_form %}
           {{ field.attribute.key }}
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

But you may change the for attribute to something else from the views because it might cause error if you  call it repeatedly like so:

```
{{ attribute.attribute.key }}
```

The 1st attribute is the name for your looping statement while the

2nd attribute would probably the name of your object from models.Variation then;

3rd is the object you wanted to access to that models

Comment: Sorry about that, I just revised it. I think this now will work.